# Is there any way to see mass of a part in autodyn?

Tags: ansys

I'm trying to model a blast in autodyn using axysimmetric wedge formulation in order to remap a 3d problem later. But I don't know how to calculate the radius of the explosive to match the given mass, or how to see the mass of constituent of multibody Euler part. Does anyone have any suggestions on this account?

Comment: You can calculate the radius of the explosive since you should know the density - or at least can look it up. Usually an explosive analysis assumes a spherical or hemi-spherical charge. Occasionally a cylindrical charge is used. Regardless you can calculate the radius from the geometry (volume) and density if you are given the mass.

Comment: Thank you for your responce, mg4w! So if I understand you correctly the radius of the spherical explosive R can be calculated from $\frac{4}3\pi(R^3-r^3)\rho=m$, where r is the minimum radius of the wedge?

Comment: yes that is correct. However you are likely dealing with a solid sphere so it would just be $\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3 \rho = m$, since the inner radius would be zero.

Comment: Yeah, but in autodyn the wedge's predef part minimal radius can't be zero, so r doesn't vanish.